# Regular sequences in polynomial rings.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain (in the application I have in mind $R = \mathbf{Z}_p$, the p-adic integers) and let $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ be a sequence of
polynomials in $R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, where $k < n$. Is there an algorithm for deciding whether $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ is a regular sequence?